# MySQL Calculate percentage change of sales between years based on SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, cumulative-sum, mysql-5.6

I have a data warehouse where the SELECT (and SUM) query has the following output.

```
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| YEAR | ITEM TYPE | TOTAL_ITEMS | TOTAL_COST |
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 2009 | TYPE-1    |          19 |        330 |
| 2009 | TYPE-2    |           1 |         10 |
| 2009 | TYPE-3    |          11 |        190 |
| 2010 | TYPE-1    |          11 |        220 |
| 2010 | TYPE-2    |           7 |        230 |
| 2010 | TYPE-3    |           3 |        360 |
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

My question is how to create a new column where to calculate the total cost difference between 2009 and 2010 (where 2009 is as a base) in percentage.

So the output will be something like this:

```
  +------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| YEAR | ITEM TYPE | TOTAL_ITEMS | TOTAL_COST | ItemDiff | CostDiff |
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2009 | TYPE-1    |          19 |        330 | 0%       | 0        |
| 2009 | TYPE-2    |           1 |         10 | 0%       | 0        |
| 2009 | TYPE-3    |          11 |        190 | 0%       | 0        |
| 2010 | TYPE-1    |          11 |        220 | -42.11%  | -33.33%  |
| 2010 | TYPE-2    |           7 |        230 | 1000%    | 2200%    |
| 2010 | TYPE-3    |           3 |        360 | -72.73%  | 80.47%   |
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

The ITEM TYPE is a category which is composed from several items with different prices. I need to calculate changes per category not per item.

The query I've got so far is

```
SELECT
  date_dim.year,
  item_dim.item_type,
  SUM(fact.total_item)TotalItems,
  SUM(fact.total_cost) AS TotalCost 
FROM fact
  INNER JOIN date_dim
    ON fact.date_key = date_dim.date_key
  INNER JOIN item_dim
    ON fact.item_key = item_dim.item_key
WHERE date_dim.year BETWEEN 2009 AND 2011
GROUP BY date_dim.year,
         item_dim.item_type
```

Please have a look at the following fiddle where the schema and the query are already built.

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e53c0/2

Here is the simplified ERD...

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AATTX.png)

Thank you in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query how to achieve that:

**Using MySQL Common Table Expression** (This doesn't run on sqlfiddle)

```
WITH summary_table AS 
  (SELECT
    substr(date_dim.year,1,4) year,
    item_dim.item_type,
    SUM(fact.total_item) TotalItems,
    SUM(fact.total_cost) AS TotalCost 
  FROM fact
    INNER JOIN date_dim
      ON fact.date_key = date_dim.date_key
    INNER JOIN item_dim
      ON fact.item_key = item_dim.item_key
  WHERE date_dim.year BETWEEN 2009 AND 2011
  GROUP BY date_dim.year,
           item_dim.item_type) 
  SELECT  
     A.*, 
     CASE WHEN (A.TotalItems IS NULL OR B.TotalItems IS NULL OR B.TotalItems=0) THEN 0 ELSE
       (A.TotalItems - B.TotalItems)*100/B.TotalItems END AS ItemDiff,
     CASE WHEN (A.TotalCost IS NULL OR B.TotalCost IS NULL OR B.TotalCost=0) THEN 0 ELSE
        (A.TotalCost - B.TotalCost)*100/B.TotalCost END AS CostDiff
  FROM summary_table A LEFT JOIN summary_table B
   ON A.YEAR=(B.YEAR+1) AND A.ITEM_TYPE=B.ITEM_TYPE;
```

**Without CTE** (See [demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e53c0/29))

```
SELECT 
     A.*, 
     CASE WHEN (A.TotalItems IS NULL OR B.TotalItems IS NULL OR B.TotalItems=0) THEN 0 ELSE
       (A.TotalItems - B.TotalItems)*100/B.TotalItems END AS ItemDiff,
     CASE WHEN (A.TotalCost IS NULL OR B.TotalCost IS NULL OR B.TotalCost=0) THEN 0 ELSE
        (A.TotalCost - B.TotalCost)*100/B.TotalCost END AS CostDiff
FROM (SELECT
    substr(date_dim.year,1,4) year,
    item_dim.item_type,
    SUM(fact.total_item)TotalItems,
    SUM(fact.total_cost) AS TotalCost 
  FROM fact
    INNER JOIN date_dim
      ON fact.date_key = date_dim.date_key
    INNER JOIN item_dim
      ON fact.item_key = item_dim.item_key
  WHERE date_dim.year BETWEEN 2009 AND 2011
  GROUP BY date_dim.year,
           item_dim.item_type) A LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    substr(date_dim.year,1,4) year,
    item_dim.item_type,
    SUM(fact.total_item)TotalItems,
    SUM(fact.total_cost) AS TotalCost 
  FROM fact
    INNER JOIN date_dim
      ON fact.date_key = date_dim.date_key
    INNER JOIN item_dim
      ON fact.item_key = item_dim.item_key
  WHERE date_dim.year BETWEEN 2009 AND 2011
  GROUP BY date_dim.year,
           item_dim.item_type) B
ON A.YEAR=(B.YEAR+1) AND A.ITEM_TYPE=B.ITEM_TYPE;
```

Comment: omg... thank you so much ... its works out of the box.. beautiful query. thank you again

Comment: You are welcom @MichaelJ